# a list representation of connected components labelled

Tags: c++

I did the weighted quick union with path compression(Sedgewick & Wayne) and got filled an array, let's say, id[i] in which connected components are laid according to different roots. IF id[i] == i, then i is a root. if not, id[i] is a parent of i. My question is how do I get "a list of connected components (differing roots)" from this array. I am confused of how to find root of each id because these are pointing only to immediate parent.

The following are id[i] values (parent or grandparent) in the order of i:
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 11 13 14 1 1 1 1 19 20 1 1 23 24 24 23 27 27 57 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 41 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 50 51 51 29 29 29 29 57 29 29 60 57 57 57 57 57 65 65 29 69 69 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 87 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 96 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 29 29 110 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 118 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 144 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 144 144 144 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 57 57 57 57 57 57 57

My code is:

```
    vector<vector<short>> components() {
       vector<short> root, separated;
       vector<vector<short>> list;

    for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++) { 
        if (i == id[i]) root.push_back(i);
        else id[i] = id[id[i]];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < root.size(); j++) {
     separated.clear();
     for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++) { if (root[j] == id[i])  separated.push_back(i); }
     list.push_back(separated);
     }
     std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), [](const vector<short> & a, const  vector<short> & b) { return a.size() > b.size(); });
     return list; // return a list of connected components labelled
     }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I have managed to fix the above code as follows:

vector<vector<short>> components() { 
    vector<short> root, separated;
    vector<vector<short>> list; 
    for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++) id[i] = find(i); 
    for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++) if (i == id[i]) root.push_back(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < root.size(); j++) {
        separated.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++) { if (root[j] == id[i]) separated.push_back(i); }
        list.push_back(separated);
    }
    std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), [](const vector<short> & a, const vector<short> & b) { return a.size() > b.size(); });
    return list; 
}

int find(int p) {
    while (p != id[p]) {
       id[p] = id[id[p]];    
       p = id[p];
    }
    return p;
}
```

Now it is working fine.

Comment: Would you be able to help someone with that? "My code is .."? The data dump may help someone interested in digging ...

Comment: Ted Lyngmo:    The above array id has 177 value, each pointing to parents, of those which  20 are roots. The task is labeling these to different groups according to 20 roots.

Comment: Data that I have is id[] ={0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 11 11 13 14 1 1 1 1 19 20 1 1 23 24 24 23 27 27 57 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 41 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 50 51 51 29 29 29 29 57 29 29 60 57 57 57 57 57 65 65 29 69 69 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 87 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 96 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 29 29 110 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 118 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 144 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 144 144 144 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 57 57 57 57 57 57 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 57 57 57 57 57 57 57}. My job is to separate these into 20 groups

Comment: What's your own take on it? Ideas?

Comment: I have modified the function components() and add another function find(), the latter of which gives the root of group each id[] belongs to.

Comment: This question still looks open, but it seems that you solved it yourself? If that's the case I suggest that you remove the question.